# How to Hook _PyObject_Malloc Using ctypes and PyMem_GetAllocator in Python 3.4?

Tags: python, ctypes, python-3.4, python-internals

I thought I could hook the `_PyObject_Malloc` call using `ctypes` and `PyMem_GetAllocator` in Python 3.4.

Here's the setup:

```
from ctypes import *

MALLOC = CFUNCTYPE(c_void_p, c_void_p, c_size_t)
REALLOC = CFUNCTYPE(c_void_p, c_void_p, c_size_t)
FREE = CFUNCTYPE(c_void_p, c_void_p)

class PyMemAllocator(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('ctx', c_void_p),
        ('malloc', MALLOC),
        ('realloc', REALLOC),
        ('free', FREE),
    ]

allocator = PyMemAllocator()
```

Then I try to get the current allocator and replace it with my own:

```
PYMEM_DOMAIN_RAW = 0
PYMEM_DOMAIN_MEM = 1
PYMEM_DOMAIN_OBJ = 2

pythonapi.PyMem_GetAllocator(PYMEM_DOMAIN_OBJ, byref(allocator))

libc = CDLL('libc.dylib')
printf = libc.printf

pyobject_malloc = MALLOC(allocator.malloc)

def py_malloc(ctx, size):
    printf(b'malloc-ing: %i bytes\n', size)
    return pyobject_malloc(ctx, size)

allocator.malloc = MALLOC(py_malloc)

pythonapi.PyMem_SetAllocator(PYMEM_DOMAIN_OBJ, byref(allocator))
```

Finally to test things out:

```
values = [object() for value in range(1000)]
print(values[:5])
```

Altogether, this results in:

```
$ python3 py_memory.py 
malloc-ing: 136 bytes
malloc-ing: 64 bytes
malloc-ing: 64 bytes
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I tried building a debug version and running it under Valgrind:

```
$ valgrind --dsymutil=yes ../../cpython/python.exe py_memory.py
...
==30339== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==30339==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x104490FE0
==30339==    at 0x101C77A19: classify_argument (x86-ffi64.c:143)
==30339==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==30339==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==30339==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==30339==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==30339==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 16777216.
...
Segmentation fault: 11
```

So then I tried looking at [classify_argument](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.4/Modules/_ctypes/libffi_osx/x86/x86-ffi64.c#L143) but got lost there. Seems like I'm missing a type annotation like `c_void_p` or `c_size_t` somewhere but I'm not sure where.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: Of course you get a stack overflow. The small-object allocator is used all over the interpreter -- such as calling `PyTuple_New` in [`_CallPythonObject`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.4.3/Modules/_ctypes/callbacks.c#l126), called to create the args tuple for calling your `py_malloc` function.

Comment: If you still care to do this, you can use ctypes for the setup, but you'll need to build a small C library that has the hook functions and pointers to the original allocators.

Comment: @eryksun I thought that might be the case. Thanks.